# Restricted partitions of n into 3 positive integers

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

It is required to find the number of partitions of a multiple of six into 3 positive terms.

Find $P(6n, 3)$ for $n \geq 0$. I'm want to know, what is the way to do it, if there is no formula depends of $n$. How to find it in combinatorics way? And how to do it with recurrent sequences?

For a certain formula, it’s easy, suppose the answer will be $3n^2$.
Then $$P(6n, 3) = P(6n-3, 3) + P(6n - 1, 2) =$$
$$= P(6n-6, 3) + P(6n-4,2) + P(6n-1,2) =$$
$$= P(6n-6, 3) + \left[\frac{6n-4}{2}\right] + \left[\frac{6n-1}{2}\right] =$$
$$= P(6n-6, 3) + 6n - 3$$

And with induction finally $3n^2 = 3(n-1)^2 + 6n - 3$.

What if there is no formula?

Comment: The title requires the terms not be duplicated, but the body does not.  Which is it? Is $6=2+2+2$ acceptable?

Comment: @RossMillikan yes, your exaple is okay. Also 6=4+1+1=3+2+1

Comment: I would let $k$ be the smallest number.  Then you have to partition $6n-k$ into two numbers at least $k$.  How many ways to do that?  Now sum over $k$ from $1$ to $2n$

Comment: @RossMillikan in title I mean that 4 + 1 + 1 and 1 + 4 + 1 is the same.

Comment: Partitions as opposed to compositions do not care about the order of the parts, so using that word already tells us that $4+1+1$ and $1+4+1$ are the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99186/discussion-between-evgeny-and-ross-millikan).

Comment: This question is related to [OEIS A069905](https://oeis.org/A069905) and [OEIS A001399](https://oeis.org/A001399). Even if a closed form is not obvious, most of these questions can be solved with recurrence relations and generating functions, and *[generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html)* provides many approaches to finding possible closed forms

Answer (score 0):

There's a closed form formula for what you're looking for. The generalized formula for $p(n,3)$ is,
$$p(n,3)=\frac{1}{72}\left(6n^{2}-7-9\left(-1\right)^{n}+16\cos\left(\frac{2}{3}\pi n\right)\right)$$
And in your generalized case, $p(6n,3)$ it is;

$$p(6n,3)=\frac{1}{72}\left(6^{3}n^{2}+16\left(\cos\left(4\pi n\right)-1\right)\right)$$

Comment: Can you show how did you get it? And also, I think, in you case n divisible by 3, right?